# Apache pig rank

Tags: apache-pig

I have a list of values

```
9, 8, 28, 66, 7
```

The rank function in pig is giving me a ranked output of - (Desc)

```
9
8
7
66
28
```

**Expected Output**

```
66
28
9
8
7
```

It seems like Pig is only considering the first digit?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it's not working in your case. Probably I can help you with more details on your problem. Here is what I did and it's working.
here is a sample file a.log.

> cat a.log

```
1

9

8

28

66

7
```

I wrote these two lines on grunt shell:

```
grunt >  q = Load '/home/anurag/a.log' USING PigStorage(',') as (a:int);

grunt > C = rank q by a DESC;
```

now when dump C. Output is

```
(1,66)

(2,28)

(3,9)

(4,8)

(5,7)

(6,1)
```

which was expected

P.S: I am using Pig 0.12